# Hugin image/layer order

Tags: post-processing, panorama, linux, layers, hugin

I made some huge panorama but to complete the background i used some 'low-res' pictures from a much wider lens.

Everything is well connected, but the image order is not the order from the "Images" tab, and the finished connected image is (in 95% of the area) covered by the lower resolution photos(there are some places where i can see the hi-res images like this:)
[image]
After all, this piece is almost nothing, but it`s a significant quality drop(2Gpx becomes 100Mpx). 
[image]
How can i send the lower-res photos to the background, or set the higer as foreground?

PS:Hi-res photos are i0 to i111 and low-res are i112 to i123, so the order is not being applied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Mask tab you can select regions of the picture that you don't want Hugin to use in the final panorama. You just have to be careful to not mask out a part of the panorama that only exists in that low-res picture, because then you will get a hole.

Comment: Your image mask worked wonderfully. ;) It gives work to apply, but then everything works fine

Comment: Yes, it does take work to get the perfect mask, but with patience you can get hugin to behave properly.

Answer (score -1):

Images  are blended in the same order, as its in the project, so you can put lowres images to the end of project.

It's possible to reorder them on **Images** tab using button UP or DOWN ( One image for one positiion for one click).

---

Also, you can hide lowres images in preview, export panorama , hide lowres, show hires, export again and than merge them by hand ( or by calling *enblend* by yourself ).

Comment: Is it possible to reorder them?

Comment: You should read what is asked. The image order doesn't always works, and in my case, it didn't as there are various resolution/focal-length images.